# user - rating associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rating

I'm working on rails project, and i want to create some user rating system, it means that each user has the ability to leave feedback on another user, and the user can also change the score he left behind, so the question is how to implement these associations in rails correctly ?

I already have my User model here it is

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  enum role: [ :user, :admin ]

end
```

Comment: Can you please add some more details like Post model etc.?  Also, what can a user rate? A post, comment or user?

Comment: So in my case user has ability to just rate another user, that is why i posted just user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As I have understood your problem this is ONE-TO-MANY association.

User -many-> Ratings

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

> ```
>   has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
> ```

```
  enum role: [ :user, :admin ]

end
```

Now Create a Rating model which will have its attribute **rating_point**,   **user_id** and **creator_id** where user_id is on which rating is given and creator_id is the User who is giving the rating to the user.

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to: user
end
```

Try this It will solve your problem. If not please let me know.

Comment: @Kizlokizlo This answer seems to be fine. But if you have plans to extend the rating functionality for other modules like Posts and Comments, you should better look out for Polymorphic Association. If it is only the users who are supposed to be rated, just go with this answer :)